# Rails 5+ Show All Custom Rake Tasks From Rails CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5+, how do I show all custom Rake tasks from the `rails` CLI? Before Rails 5, all Rake tasks, including custom tasks, would be shown with `rake -T`. In Rails 5 and beyond, all `rake` commands have been replaced with `rails`. So naturally, `rails -T` will list available Rails commands. However, it is not listing my project's custom Rake tasks, even though running that task through the `rails` CLI will still function properly.

Comment: Does your task have a description? Try with `rails -T -A`.

Comment: actually `rails -vT`

Answer (score 1):

**Command:**

`rails -vT`

**Sample:**

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Drop, create, migrate then seed the development database'
  task database: [ 'db:drop', 'db:create', 'db:migrate', 'db:seed' ] do
    exec ('bundle install')
    puts 'Datebase Remigrated.'
  end
end
```